# google api c++ library ./prepare_dependencies.py error

Tags: c++, macos, google-fusion-tables, google-api-client, google-api-cpp-client

I am working on a google fusion table project with c++. I tried to install google api c++ library downloaded from https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client.
When I ran >> ./prepare_denpendencies.py , I got error shown below.

Can someone help me figure out where the problem is? Or can someone show me another way to use google fusion table without install the library? Thanks!

Other info:

cmake @2.8.12.2_0 (active) installed by using mac port.
Mac OS X.

```
>> ./prepare_dependencies.py 
   Build packages = True
   Download packages = True
   Installing packages = True
   Downloading files to /Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies
   Installing packages to /Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/install
Initializing....
cmake-2.8.10.2.tar.gz already exists - skipping download from http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.10.2.tar.gz
cmake-2.8.10.2 already configured
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++  Building cmake-2.8.10.2 [all]
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>>> Executing [make  all] in /Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2
[  1%] Built target cmIML_test
[  4%] Built target cmsys
[  5%] Built target cmsysTestDynload
[  6%] Built target cmsys_c
[  6%] Built target cmsysTestProcess
[  6%] Built target cmsysTestSharedForward
[  7%] Built target cmsysTestsC
[  9%] Built target cmsysTestsCxx
[ 12%] Built target cmzlib
[ 12%] Building C object Utilities/cmcurl/CMakeFiles/cmcurl.dir/cookie.c.o
In file included from /Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmcurl/cookie.c:93:
/Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmcurl/strequal.h:41:8: error: 
      expected parameter declarator
size_t strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t siz);
       ^
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:111:44: note: expanded from macro 'strlcat'
  __builtin___strlcat_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                                           ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:39:62: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz'
#define __darwin_obsz(object) __builtin_object_size (object, _USE_FORTIF...
                                                             ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:30:32: note: expanded from macro
      '_USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL'
#    define _USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL 2
                               ^
In file included from /Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmcurl/cookie.c:93:
/Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmcurl/strequal.h:41:8: error: 
      expected ')'
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:111:44: note: expanded from macro 'strlcat'
  __builtin___strlcat_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                                           ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:39:62: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz'
#define __darwin_obsz(object) __builtin_object_size (object, _USE_FORTIF...
                                                             ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:30:32: note: expanded from macro
      '_USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL'
#    define _USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL 2
                               ^
/Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmcurl/strequal.h:41:8: note: 
      to match this '('
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:111:44: note: expanded from macro 'strlcat'
  __builtin___strlcat_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                                           ^
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:39:53: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz'
#define __darwin_obsz(object) __builtin_object_size (object, _USE_FORTIF...
                                                    ^
In file included from /Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmcurl/cookie.c:93:
/Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmcurl/strequal.h:41:8: warning: 
      type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
size_t strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t siz);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:111:44: note: expanded from macro 'strlcat'
  __builtin___strlcat_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:39:31: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz'
#define __darwin_obsz(object) __builtin_object_size (object, _USE_FORTIF...
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmcurl/cookie.c:93:
/Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmcurl/strequal.h:41:8: error: 
      conflicting types for '__builtin___strlcat_chk'
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:111:3: note: expanded from macro 'strlcat'
  __builtin___strlcat_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
  ^
/Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmcurl/strequal.h:41:8: note: 
      '__builtin___strlcat_chk' is a builtin with type 'unsigned long (char *,
      const char *, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:111:3: note: expanded from macro 'strlcat'
  __builtin___strlcat_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
  ^
1 warning and 3 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [Utilities/cmcurl/CMakeFiles/cmcurl.dir/cookie.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Utilities/cmcurl/CMakeFiles/cmcurl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Failed command: [make  all] in /Users/zerocraft/KuaiPan/Course/ECEN489/google-api-cpp-client-0.1/external_dependencies/cmake-2.8.10.2
   Failed to make cmake-2.8.10.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem building cmake. You can install a pre-built cmake binary from www.cmake.org and remove the cmake build from the prepare script. Or you can change the script to pull a more recent version of cmake. I just tried building the current http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.0/cmake-3.0.2.tar.gz on OSx with Xcode 5 and it built fine.

Comment: Thanks! I tried but still have the error. Finally we give up using google api in c++.